# Inserting User Inputted String into Linux commands [python script]?

Tags: python, linux, string, command

Apologies if this question is trivial, I'm an amateur with python..

I'm currently in the process of attempting to automate a series of linux commands,
using a python script. (Specifically in relation to the downloading and analysis of chandra telescope data using ciao commands)

In short what I'm aiming for is that the script asks the user to enter a 5 character long numerical string, which is stored as a variable and subsequently inserted into commands, to be run from the script.

E.G the following commands, where the asterisks would be replaced by the user inputed string.

```
import os
os.system("download_chandra_obsid *****")
os.chdir("usersc/####/Downloads/*****") 
os.system("dmkeypar acisf*****0N003_full_img2.fits dec echo=yes")
```

etc

Is there a simple way to implement this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you are not using any Python facilities in your code, it would be less clunky if you just put the commands in a regular script (`cmd` or Powershell for Windows; `sh` or Bash for U*x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

user_inputted = input('Enter your string')
# Perform validations on the input like length etc.
os.system("download_chandra_obsid {}".format(used_inputted))
os.chdir("usersc/####/Downloads/{}".format(used_inputted))
os.system("dmkeypar acisf{}0N003_full_img2.fits dec echo=yes".format(used_inputted))
```

Comment: Following your comment (even though deleted) I've tested your claims os.system wont recognize {}: `os.system('echo {}'.format('hello world'))` prints `hello world`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After testing this out it seems to me that this isn't working, seemingly because the os.system commands do not recognise the {} as an input variable... For example when I ran the command                
     import.os                                                                                        
     Obsid = input('please enter a 5 digit observation ID: ')                                                
     print(Obsid)                                  
     os.system("donwload_chandra_obsid {}").format(Obsid)

Comment: I revieve the following terminal error "skipping ObsID {} as it was not found on archive site"

Comment: Add your format before the `)` sign. right after the double quotes closing the string `"`

Comment: Should look like this : `os.system("donwload_chandra_obsid {}".format(Obsid)) `

Comment: Similarly if I randomly test with test with os.system("{}").format.(Obsid) even though this command does not exist the returned error is that {}: command not found..... I'm not sure why I'm experiencing these issues?

Comment: Ahh perfect, The misplace bracket seems to be the root of the problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get number from user using `number = input("Please type five digit number").strip()`. If you want to check if it's a valid number, use this construction:

```
while True:
    num = input("Please type five digit number").strip()
    if num.isdigit() and len(num) == 5:
         break
```

Then use `.format()` with every that string to add the number there like this:

```
os.system("download_chandra_obsid {0}".format(num))
```

(This will only work with python 2.6+, I think)
See https://pyformat.info/#simple or [python docs](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format) for more details on `str.format()`